# Removing one letter from a word

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So Is it possible to remove one letter from a string? For example

String Word = "Hello";

I want to create a function where decrementation happens like if you clicked it it will be Hell then Hel then He then H and "" is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily remove trailing characters from a `string` by using the `string.Remove(int)` method. Per the [MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.remove?view=netframework-4.7.2):

> Returns a new `string` in which all the characters in the current
>   instance, beginning at a specified position and continuing through the
>   last position, have been deleted.

You then assign the return value from the method to your variable to remove the last character every time the button is clicked.

```
private string sample = "Hello";
private void button_click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (sample.Length > 0)
        sample = sample.Remove(sample.Length - 1);
}
```

There are many ways to accomplish this task; for more information feel free to perform a Google search on `string` manipulation in `C#`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
public string Chopsta(string val) 
   => val?.Length > 0 ? val.Substring(0, val.Length - 1) : val;
```